# Angular and C# project in Docker - error 500

Tags: angular, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I have created an empty project, .net core, MVC with Angular using visual studio.
The project works, I added docker support and it works fine.
BUT, when i delete the ClientApp provided and do

```
ng new ClientApp
```

Building and running the docker container results in just error 500. Nothing in the console. 
Running the app outside of docker it loads fine??
I cannot see the issue at all:

```
    #See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
    && apt-get install nodejs -yq
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/TheRedDwarf.csproj", "src/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/TheRedDwarf.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src"
RUN dotnet build "TheRedDwarf.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TheRedDwarf.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TheRedDwarf.dll"]
```

Can anyone say as to why? The only difference is the angular part is now up-to-date but I can do dotnet run and its all running??

I've even gone and done as said here
[Medium: Docker and Angular](https://medium.com/@ali.bahrami/deploy-an-angular-asp-net-core-webapi-on-docker-ab3546a06803)

Still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it.
The new angular app was outputting to **dist/ClientApp**, it used to be configured to just '**dist**' so when the application is published it wouldn't be able to find the files, files in the dist folder it only uses when publishing - hence why it works outside of docker, I was just doing `dotnet run`!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `dotnet-cli` or `visual studio` to create `aspnet core with angular`

```
dotnet new angular
```

dotnet create a project with angular.

In `.csproj` file you can see some steps that build angular app when you publish your project.

I used to config my DockerFile like yours
but, there is some drawback, for example
install node in docker image when you change some `.cs` file and its make the build time so long

I decided to choose different way for building image

```
yaml
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebUI/WebUI.csproj", "WebUI/"]

RUN dotnet restore "WebUI/WebUI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebUI"
RUN dotnet build "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Setup NodeJs
# RUN apt-get update && \
#     apt-get install -y wget && \
#     apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
#     wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
#     apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

FROM node:lts-alpine as build-angular
RUN mkdir -p /app/publish/ClientApp
COPY ["WebUI/ClientApp/package.json", "/app/publish/ClientApp"]
WORKDIR "/app/publish/ClientApp"
RUN npm install
COPY "WebUI/ClientApp/." .
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebUI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebUI.dll"]
```

and i remove some steps that build angular project in publish state

```
   xml
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->

    <!-- <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" /> -->
    <!-- <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod" /> -->


    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

It works for me. I hope it can help others.